# How to make a wavy surface material like this (Chocolate Bar)

Tags: materials

I am trying to model a chocolate bar and done everythin except the wavy texture on the surface. Couldn't find a way to make a such wave texture. I tried using 'Wave Texture' but it's too ordinary for the material I want. Here's an example photo of the wavy surface that I want:

[image: Chocolate Bar]

As you see it's more random and on the side edges it has a different texture shape.
Can someone help?
My attempt with 2 wave textures:

[image: attempt]

Comment: what does it give with one or 2 Wave Texture? Or you could sculpt?

Comment: I edited the post, this result is with 2 wave textures

Comment: I'm not sure how to have less effect on the sides, have your tried to sculpt? Here is a try (the details are a little bit too big) https://zupimages.net/up/22/15/gf68.jpg

Comment: this looks great to be honest, can you show your process of doing this work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it with the sculpt tools:

Create a cube, stretch it, subdivide and bevel its edges:

[image]

To get a topology that is high enough for sculpting you can either subdivide with a *Subdivision Surface* modifier and apply, or enable the sculpt *Dyntopo* option, or use the *Multiresolution* modifier. With the latter solution, click several times on the *Subdivide* button, put all the levels at the same value:

[image]

Switch to *Sculpt* mode, disable the *Display Fast Navigate* option to avoid the glitches when you'll rotate your view:

[image]

Begin to sculpt, use mainly the *Draw* brush I guess, left click to create bumps, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> left click to dig, <kbd>Shift</kbd> left click to smooth. With this solution the sculpting is only virtual, you can see your intial shape if you disable the modifier visibility:

[image]

Give your object a material with chocolate color and lower the *Roughness* a bit down. You can add a bit of fake bump, and also create a b&w mask if you want to create some hazelnut sctraches, etc:

[image]

Now you can either apply the modifier and you'll have real topology, or keep it and bake the bumps, in that case you'll need to activate the *Bake from Multires* option in the *Bake* panel, choose *Bake Type > Normal*, and also put the modifier's *Level Viewport* at 0 before the bake.

Comment: thank you ser! this is a very clear and good explanation

Answer (score 7):

Late to this, and I think [@moonboots answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/260799/35559) is the way to go, for one bar. But if you want lots? And all different? This is a more procedural, shader-only approach:

- The little reference looks to me like a stretched texture, on the sides
- The 'Ripple Control' cluster does interact with itself a little, you might think bits of it are redundant.. but if you play with it, it gives quite fine control, especially over the clipping of the texture at one end or the other.

[image]

This sort of result.. (Cycles, Displacement:)

[image]

[image]

Comment: ok but too many bar is bad for health

Comment: @moonboots Worry no more! RB Vapochox® are completely calorie and enjoyment-free!